# urllib2 file name

Tags: python, url, urllib2

If I open a file using urllib2, like so:

```
remotefile = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/somefile.zip')
```

Is there an easy way to get the file name other then parsing the original URL?

EDIT: changed openfile to urlopen... not sure how that happened.

EDIT2: I ended up using:

```
filename = url.split('/')[-1].split('#')[0].split('?')[0]
```

Unless I'm mistaken, this should strip out all potential queries as well.

Comment: i think it's not corect. I mean urllib2.openfile(...)

Comment: Do make sure you know what you want in these two cases: trailing slash (`http://example.com/somefile/`)  and no path: `http://example.com`   Your example will fail on the latter for sure (returning "example.com").  So will @insin's final answer.  That's another reason why using urlsplit is good advice.

Comment: from the response headers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783269/python-httplib-urllib-get-filename

Comment: Lots of answers here miss the fact that there are two places to look for a file name: the URL and the Content-Disposition header field. All the current answers that mention the header neglect to mention that cgi.parse_header() will parse it correctly. There is a better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11783319/205212

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Did you mean [urllib2.urlopen](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-urllib2.html#l2h-3928)?

You could potentially lift the *intended* filename *if* the server was sending a Content-Disposition header by checking `remotefile.info()['Content-Disposition']`, but as it is I think you'll just have to parse the url.

You could use `urlparse.urlsplit`, but if you have any URLs like at the second example, you'll end up having to pull the file name out yourself anyway:

```
>>> urlparse.urlsplit('http://example.com/somefile.zip')
('http', 'example.com', '/somefile.zip', '', '')
>>> urlparse.urlsplit('http://example.com/somedir/somefile.zip')
('http', 'example.com', '/somedir/somefile.zip', '', '')
```

Might as well just do this:

```
>>> 'http://example.com/somefile.zip'.split('/')[-1]
'somefile.zip'
>>> 'http://example.com/somedir/somefile.zip'.split('/')[-1]
'somefile.zip'
```

Comment: Use posixpath.basename() instead of manually splitting on '/'.

Comment: I would *always* use urlsplit() and never straight string splitting.  The latter will choke if you have an URL that has a fragment or query appended, say http://example.com/filename.html?cookie=55#Section_3.

Comment: What about escaped characters?  Should those be decoded first?

Answer (score 13):

If you only want the file name itself, assuming that there's no query variables at the end like http://example.com/somedir/somefile.zip?foo=bar then you can use os.path.basename for this:

```
[user@host]$ python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54869, Apr 18 2007, 22:08:04) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename("http://example.com/somefile.zip")
'somefile.zip'
>>> os.path.basename("http://example.com/somedir/somefile.zip")
'somefile.zip'
>>> os.path.basename("http://example.com/somedir/somefile.zip?foo=bar")
'somefile.zip?foo=bar'
```

Some other posters mentioned using urlparse, which will work, but you'd still need to strip the leading directory from the file name. If you use os.path.basename() then you don't have to worry about that, since it returns only the final part of the URL or file path.

Comment: Using `os.path` to parse URLs seems to rely on current OS splitting paths in the same way as URLs are split. I don't think it's guaranteed for every OS.

Comment: This won't work on Windows. Use `import posixpath; posixpath.basename` instead.

Answer (score 7):

I think that "the file name" isn't a very well defined concept when it comes to http transfers. The server might (but is not required to) provide one as "content-disposition" header, you can try to get that with `remotefile.headers['Content-Disposition']`. If this fails, you probably have to parse the URI yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Just saw this I normally do..

```
filename = url.split("?")[0].split("/")[-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `urlsplit` is the safest option:

```
url = 'http://example.com/somefile.zip'
urlparse.urlsplit(url).path.split('/')[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `urllib2.urlopen`?  There is no function called `openfile` in the `urllib2` module.

Anyway, use the `urllib2.urlparse` functions:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlparse
>>> print urlparse.urlsplit('http://example.com/somefile.zip')
('http', 'example.com', '/somefile.zip', '', '')
```

Voila.

Answer (score 2):

The `os.path.basename` function works not only for file paths, but also for urls, so you don't have to manually parse the URL yourself. Also, it's important to note that you should use `result.url` instead of the original url in order to follow redirect responses:

```
import os
import urllib2
result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
real_url = urllib2.urlparse.urlparse(result.url)
filename = os.path.basename(real_url.path)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also combine both of the two best-rated answers :
Using urllib2.urlparse.urlsplit() to get the path part of the URL, and then os.path.basename for the actual file name.

Full code would be :

```
>>> remotefile=urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> try:
>>>   filename=remotefile.info()['Content-Disposition']
>>> except KeyError:
>>>   filename=os.path.basename(urllib2.urlparse.urlsplit(url).path)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends what you mean by parsing. There is no way to get the filename without parsing the URL, i.e. the remote server doesn't give you a filename. However, you don't have to do much yourself, there's the `urlparse` module:

```
In [9]: urlparse.urlparse('http://example.com/somefile.zip')
Out[9]: ('http', 'example.com', '/somefile.zip', '', '', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

not that I know of.

but you can parse it easy enough like this:

`url = 'http://example.com/somefile.zip'
print url.split('/')[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,urllib2
resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/index.html')
my_url = resp.geturl()

os.path.split(my_url)[1]

# 'index.html'
```

This is not openfile, but maybe still helps :)

Answer (score 0):

using requests, but you can do it easy with urllib(2)

```
import requests
from urllib import unquote
from urlparse import urlparse

sample = requests.get(url)

if sample.status_code == 200:
    #has_key not work here, and this help avoid problem with names

    if filename == False:

        if 'content-disposition' in sample.headers.keys():
            filename = sample.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[-1].replace('"','').replace(';','')

        else:

            filename = urlparse(sample.url).query.split('/')[-1].split('=')[-1].split('&')[-1]

            if not filename:

                if url.split('/')[-1] != '':
                    filename = sample.url.split('/')[-1].split('=')[-1].split('&')[-1]
                    filename = unquote(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use simple regular expression here. Something like:

```
In [26]: import re
In [27]: pat = re.compile('.+[\/\?#=]([\w-]+\.[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)?$)')
In [28]: test_set 

['http://www.google.com/a341.tar.gz',
 'http://www.google.com/a341.gz',
 'http://www.google.com/asdasd/aadssd.gz',
 'http://www.google.com/asdasd?aadssd.gz',
 'http://www.google.com/asdasd#blah.gz',
 'http://www.google.com/asdasd?filename=xxxbl.gz']

In [30]: for url in test_set:
   ....:     match = pat.match(url)
   ....:     if match and match.groups():
   ....:         print(match.groups()[0])
   ....:         

a341.tar.gz
a341.gz
aadssd.gz
aadssd.gz
blah.gz
xxxbl.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [PurePosixPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePosixPath) which is not operating system—dependent and handles urls gracefully is the pythonic solution:

```
>>> from pathlib import PurePosixPath
>>> path = PurePosixPath('http://example.com/somefile.zip')
>>> path.name
'somefile.zip'
>>> path = PurePosixPath('http://example.com/nested/somefile.zip')
>>> path.name
'somefile.zip'
```

Notice how there is no network traffic here or anything (i.e. those urls don't go anywhere) - just using standard parsing rules.