# How to download a file using python in a 'smarter' way?

Tags: python, http, download

I need to download several files via http in Python.

The most obvious way to do it is just using urllib2:

```
import urllib2
u = urllib2.urlopen('http://server.com/file.html')
localFile = open('file.html', 'w')
localFile.write(u.read())
localFile.close()
```

But I'll have to deal with the URLs that are nasty in some way, say like this: `http://server.com/!Run.aspx/someoddtext/somemore?id=121&m=pdf`. When downloaded via the browser, the file has a human-readable name, ie. `accounts.pdf`.

Is there any way to handle that in python, so I don't need to know the file names and hardcode them into my script?

Comment: Is the filename on the server relevant? Presumably these files have some meaning to you, so you ought to be able to name them yourself. If the names don't have meaning, come up with a random unique name yourself (uuids perhaps?)

Comment: I'd love to have file names readable and meaningful. The issue is, the script will take URLs to download from from a text file, and the URLs will be added and removed by a non-technical person.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Download scripts like that tend to push a header telling the user-agent what to name the file:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="the filename.ext"
```

If you can grab that header, you can get the proper filename.

There's [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163009/urllib2-file-name) that has a little bit of code to offer up for `Content-Disposition`-grabbing.

```
remotefile = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/somefile.zip')
remotefile.info()['Content-Disposition']
```

Comment: No, they might be redirecting to a plain file. But if it's like most download scripts, they're pushing the content-disposition. By all means check.

Comment: If it redirects me to a plain file it's easy too, I can access actual url via remotefile.url, can't I?

Answer (score 35):

Based on comments and @Oli's anwser, I made a solution like this:

```
from os.path import basename
from urlparse import urlsplit

def url2name(url):
    return basename(urlsplit(url)[2])

def download(url, localFileName = None):
    localName = url2name(url)
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    if r.info().has_key('Content-Disposition'):
        # If the response has Content-Disposition, we take file name from it
        localName = r.info()['Content-Disposition'].split('filename=')[1]
        if localName[0] == '"' or localName[0] == "'":
            localName = localName[1:-1]
    elif r.url != url: 
        # if we were redirected, the real file name we take from the final URL
        localName = url2name(r.url)
    if localFileName: 
        # we can force to save the file as specified name
        localName = localFileName
    f = open(localName, 'wb')
    f.write(r.read())
    f.close()
```

It takes file name from Content-Disposition; if it's not present, uses filename from the URL (if redirection happened, the final URL is taken into account).

Comment: I found this useful. But to download bigger files, without storing them full content in memory, I had to find out this, copying your 'r' to 'f':
import shutil
shutil.copyfileobj(r, f)

Comment: Worked very well, but I would wrap `urlsplit(url)[2]` with a call to `urllib.unquote`, otherwise the filenames would be percent-encoded. Here is how I'm doing: `return basename(urllib.unquote(urlsplit(url)[2]))`

Answer (score 23):

Combining much of the above, here is a more pythonic solution:

```
import urllib2
import shutil
import urlparse
import os

def download(url, fileName=None):
    def getFileName(url,openUrl):
        if 'Content-Disposition' in openUrl.info():
            # If the response has Content-Disposition, try to get filename from it
            cd = dict(map(
                lambda x: x.strip().split('=') if '=' in x else (x.strip(),''),
                openUrl.info()['Content-Disposition'].split(';')))
            if 'filename' in cd:
                filename = cd['filename'].strip("\"'")
                if filename: return filename
        # if no filename was found above, parse it out of the final URL.
        return os.path.basename(urlparse.urlsplit(openUrl.url)[2])

    r = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url))
    try:
        fileName = fileName or getFileName(url,r)
        with open(fileName, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r,f)
    finally:
        r.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

**2 Kender**:

```
if localName[0] == '"' or localName[0] == "'":
    localName = localName[1:-1]
```

it is not safe -- web server can pass wrong formatted name as ["file.ext] or [file.ext'] or even be empty and **localName[0]** will raise exception.
Correct code can looks like this:

```
localName = localName.replace('"', '').replace("'", "")
if localName == '':
    localName = SOME_DEFAULT_FILE_NAME
```

Comment: Even better: `local_name.strip('\'"')` -- that will only strip from the beginning and end and is also more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Using `wget`:

```
custom_file_name = "/custom/path/custom_name.ext"
wget.download(url, custom_file_name)
```

Using urlretrieve:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, custom_file_name)
```

urlretrieve also creates the directory structure if not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into `'Content-Disposition'` header, see the solution by kender.

How to download a file using python in a 'smarter' way?

Posting his solution modified with a capability to specify an output folder:

```py
from os.path import basename
import os
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
import urllib.request

def url2name(url):
    return basename(urlsplit(url)[2])

def download(url, out_path):
    localName = url2name(url)
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    if r.info().has_key('Content-Disposition'):
        # If the response has Content-Disposition, we take file name from it
        localName = r.info()['Content-Disposition'].split('filename=')[1]
        if localName[0] == '"' or localName[0] == "'":
            localName = localName[1:-1]
    elif r.url != url: 
        # if we were redirected, the real file name we take from the final URL
        localName = url2name(r.url)

    localName = os.path.join(out_path, localName)
    f = open(localName, 'wb')
    f.write(r.read())
    f.close()

download("https://example.com/demofile", '/home/username/tmp')
```

I have just updated the answer of kender for python3

Comment: Instead of parsing `r.info()` yourself, you probably can use `r.info().get_filename()` or `r.headers().get_filename()`