# urlretrieve returns an empty file

Tags: python, download, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to use urlretrieve to download files from urls that take the form:

**http://example.com/download.php?id=6456&name=foo**

yet for some reason I just get an empty response.

I've tried the method suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862173/how-to-download-a-file-using-python-in-a-smarter-way) didn't seem to help because

```
remotefile.info()
```

doesn't contain the key 'content-disposition', only

```
['content-length', 'x-powered-by', 'refresh', 'server', 'connection', 'date', 'content-type']
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information from [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

> info() — return the meta-information
>   of the page, such as headers, in the
>   form of an httplib.HTTPMessage
>   instance (see Quick Reference to HTTP
>   Headers)

What keys do you have in dict remotefile.info()?

Can you get a full header information?

Comment: Thanks, your answer put me on the right track to a solution. Looking at the response headers I found a url pointing me to the login page. Forgot I have to do that first