# Check for `urllib.urlretrieve(url, file_name)` Completion Status

Tags: python, urllib

How do I check to see if `urllib.urlretrieve(url, file_name)` has completed before allowing my program to advance to the next statement?

Take for example the following code snippet:

```
import traceback
import sys
import Image
from urllib import urlretrieve

try:
        print "Downloading gif....."
        urlretrieve(imgUrl, "tides.gif")
        # Allow time for image to download/save:
        time.sleep(5)
        print "Gif Downloaded."
    except:
        print "Failed to Download new GIF"
        raw_input('Press Enter to exit...')
        sys.exit()

    try:
        print "Converting GIF to JPG...."
        Image.open("tides.gif").convert('RGB').save("tides.jpg")
        print "Image Converted"
    except Exception, e:
        print "Conversion FAIL:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        traceback.print_exc()
        pass
```

When the download of 'tides.gif' via `urlretrieve(imgUrl, "tides.gif")` takes longer than `time.sleep(seconds)` resulting in an empty or not-complete file, `Image.open("tides.gif")` raises an `IOError` (due to a tides.gif file of size 0 kB).

How can I check the status of `urlretrieve(imgUrl, "tides.gif")`, allowing my program to advance only after the statement has been successfully completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Requests is nicer than urllib but you should be able to do this to synchronously download the file:

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen(imgUrl)
with open("tides.gif", "wb") as imgFile:
    imgFile.write(f.read())
# you won't get to this print until you've downloaded
# all of the image at imgUrl or an exception is raised
print "Got it!"
```

The downside of this is it will need to buffer the whole file in memory so if you're downloading a lot of images at once you may end up using a ton of ram.  It's unlikely, but still worth knowing.

Answer (score 2):

I would use python requests from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html instead of plain urllib2. requests is synchronous by default so it won't progress to the next line of code without getting your image first.

Comment: There is also an async model within `requests`, but you need `gevent` and `greenlet`

Answer (score 0):

**I found a similar question here:** [Why is "raise IOError("cannot identify image file")"showing up only part of the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593158/why-is-raise-ioerrorcannot-identify-image-fileshowing-up-only-part-of-the)

To be more specific, look at the answer to the question. The user points to a couple of other threads that explain exactly how to solve the problem in multiple ways. The first one, which you may be interested in, includes a progress bar display.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer doesn't work with big files. Here is the correct solution:

```
import sys
import time
import urllib


def reporthook(count, block_size, total_size):
    if int(count * block_size * 100 / total_size) == 100:
        print 'Download completed!'

def save(url, filename):
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below :

```
import time

# ----------------------------------------------------
# Wait until the end of the download
# ----------------------------------------------------

valid=0
while valid==0:
    try:
        with open("tides.gif"):valid=1
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(1)

print "Got it !"

# ----------------------------------------------------
# //////////////////////////////////////////////////
# ----------------------------------------------------
```