# python httplib/urllib get filename

Tags: python, urllib, httplib

is there a possibillity to get the filename

```
e.g. xyz.com/blafoo/showall.html
```

if you work with urllib or httplib?

so that i can save the file under the filename on the server?

if you go to sites like

```
xyz.com/blafoo/
```

you cant see the filename.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [urllib2 file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163009/urllib2-file-name)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get filename from response http headers:

```
import cgi

response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
_, params = cgi.parse_header(response.headers.get('Content-Disposition', ''))
filename = params['filename']
```

To get filename from the URL:

```
import posixpath
import urlparse 

path = urlparse.urlsplit(URL).path
filename = posixpath.basename(path)
```

Comment: Great answer, one tiny fix. Using os.path.basename(path) is a cross platform way of doing this.

Comment: @JorgeVargas: no. `posixpath` is the correct module here. Moreover it would be a mistake to use `os.path` here. If you can't figure out "why", ask, I'll elaborate.

Comment: I'll ask: why should one use posixpath?

Comment: @KarlM.Davis: urls use `'/'` in their path segment. `os.path` on Windows may use `'\\'` that is not appropriate for urls as pathname separator. `posixpath` uses `'/'`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `urllib.request.Request`:

```
import urllib

req = urllib.request.Request(url, method='HEAD')
r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(r.info().get_filename())
```

Example :

```
In[1]: urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request('https://httpbin.org/response-headers?content-disposition=%20attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22example.csv%22', method='HEAD')).info().get_filename()
Out[1]: 'example.csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

Does not make much sense what you are asking. The only thing that you have is the URL.
Either extract the last part from the URL or you may check the HTTP response for something like

```
content-disposition: attachment;filename="foo.bar"
```

This header can be set by the server to indicate that the filename is **foo.bar**. This is usually used for file downloads or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for you question on google and I saw that it was answered in stackoverflow before I believe.

Try looking at this post:

[Using urllib2 in Python. How do I get the name of the file I am downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533880/using-urllib2-in-python-how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-file-i-am-downloading)

> The filename is usually included by the server through the
>   content-disposition header:
>
> ```
> content-disposition: attachment; filename=foo.pdf
> ```
>
> You have access to the headers through
>
> ```
> result = urllib2.urlopen(...)
> result.info() <- contains the headers
>
>
> i>>> import urllib2
> ur>>> result = urllib2.urlopen('http://zopyx.com')
> >>> print result
> <addinfourl at 4302289808 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x1006dd5d0>>
> >>> result.info()
> <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x1006fbab8>
> >>> result.info().headers
> ['Date: Mon, 04 Apr 2011 02:08:28 GMT\r\n', 'Server: Zope/(unreleased version, python 2.4.6, linux2) ZServer/1.1
> ```
>
> Plone/3.3.4\r\n', 'Content-Length: 15321\r\n', 'Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n', 'Via: 1.1 www.zopyx.com\r\n',
>   'Cache-Control: max-age=3600\r\n', 'Expires: Mon, 04 Apr 2011 03:08:28
>   GMT\r\n', 'Connection: close\r\n']
>
> See
>
> http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html