# How to mention the local drive path to the url using python-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783269/python-httplib-urllib-get-filename) link I can retrieve the path and file name.

Further all I want to name the file as-

D:\Links\filename

for eg-
[`http://www.example.com/category/location/filename`](http://www.example.com/category/location/filename)  - will be the original

D:\Links\category\location\filename.html -  is what I want to do due to which it will run as -

fttp://D:/Links/category/location/filename.html

Help / Guidance in any form is welcome.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry, this is very unclear. Where exactly are you having problems? What code do you have so far?

Comment: @DanielRoseman- the answer below works well. All I wanted to set the local drive path while parsing the url. Sorry if I was not clear enough although I got the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
import urlparse
import os

url = "http://www.example.com/category/location/filename"

url_path = urlparse.urlparse(url).path
local_filename = os.path.join(r'd:', os.sep, 'links', os.path.normpath(url_path)[1:]) + ".html"
print local_filename
```

This would give you a local filename as follows:

```
d:\links\category\location\filename.html
```

The Python [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html?highlight=urlparse#urlparse.urlparse) function can be used to extract the path from your URL, and then the [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.normpath) function can be used to fix all of the separators. Finally, [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.join) can be used to join all of your parts back together again safely.

Comment: That worked just the perfect ! thanks a lot !!!! I was unaware of os.path.normpath