# How to download a file with its original filename from GAE's blobstore?

Tags: google-app-engine, http-headers, filenames, blobstore

Once you upload a file to the blobstore, it renames it something like "s9QmBqJPuiVzWbySYvHVRg==". If you navigate to its "/serve" URL to download the file, the downloaded file is named this jumble of letters.

Is there a way to have the downloaded file retain its original filename when uploaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the file is uploaded using the `BlobUploadHandler`
the original filename is stored as name property in the newly created `BlobInfo` entity.

In the blob serve handler, you can specify that the blob should be returned as download attachment, and you can specify with what name should it be saved with

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import urllib

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, blob_info_key=None):
    blob_info_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_info_key))
    blob_info = retrieve_blob_info(blob_info_key)
    self.send_blob(blob_info, save_as=blob_info.filename)


blob_app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/_s/blob/([^/]+)', blob.ServeHandler),
], debug=config.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify blob_info.filename when using the experimental API to write a file directly to the blobstore?

Comment: There is a relevant question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697844/how-to-set-filename-property-in-blobstore

Comment: Yes, when writing a blob through file api, you can specify it a name, here is how:      file_name = files.blobstore.create(
        mime_type=content_type,
        _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=blob_name,
      )

Answer (score 0):

In the GAE admin [console](https://appengine.google.com/), BLOB viewer section, when you view an individual BLOB there is a download button on the bottom right of the viewer, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it dominoes always show that download button. I have a file of type (application/x-compress) which also says its too large for a preview - there is no download link.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you refer to is the key of the BlobInfo entity, but the original filename is stored as property.

If you want a simple way to download a file by its filename you  can use this code that I use for my ServeHandler, it works for my needs, download a file by its filename instead of blobstore key:

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    blobs = blobstore.BlobInfo.gql("WHERE filename = '%s'" %(urllib.unquote(resource)))
    if blobs.count(1) > 0:
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blobs[0].key())
        self.send_blob(blob_info,save_as=True)
```